# How to implement hierarchical navigation in angularjs?

Tags: navigation, angularjs, hierarchical-data

How would one go about implementing hierarchical navigation in angularjs? For example, given the site structure below how could it be implemented in a sidebar using angularjs?

**Recipes

. Starters

. Mains

.. Chicken

.. Vegetarian

.. Italian

... Pasta

... Pizza

. Deserts**

I'm happy enough using **ng-repeat** for a single layer, or a likely inefficient implementation of a fixed small number of layers (using nested **ng-repeat**'s), but not sure how to proceed with an arbitrary depth of navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: You can use same NG-REPEAT logic for recipes in your "categories" and "recipes" too if you want data from JSON.

```
<ul>

<li>
<a href="#"> Recipes</a>
</li>
     <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#"> Categories</a>
        </li>

        <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="recipe in recipes>
        <a href="#/recipes/{{recipe.id}}"> <img ng-src="{{recipe.imageUrl}}"></a>
        </li>
        </ul>

     </ul>
</ul>

Here recipes is list of recipes you have. {{recipe.id}} and {{recipe.imageURL}} is getting picked  from JSON file where all this data is available.

for controller.js:



var recipeControllers = angular.module('recipeControllers', []);

recipeControllers.controller('recipeSideListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
     function ($scope, $http) { 

$http.get('app/recipes/recipe.json').success(function(data){


$scope.recipes = data;


}}]);
```

Rest you can use your CSS to shift this to your side bar.
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I don't think it works in this instance. In this instance I'm not trying to list recipes, I am trying to list /categories/ of recipes.

Comment: So what I am getting is you want following structure.
 
-->Recipes 
-->--> Cateogires
-->-->--> particular recipe 

For that you can just add one more <UL> for category names and in those category you will get recipes. I will edit it.

Comment: You can use same NG-REPEAT logic for recipes in your "categories" and "recipes" too if you want data from JSON.

Comment: The bit you're missing is that I want to deal with an arbitrary depth of subcategories. For any given depth I could use n nested ng-repeats but what I am looking for is a way to handle this /without/ nesting ng-repeats by hand.

Comment: I get your problem completely now. You don't want to manipulate it by hand but via NG-repeat itself somehow automatically, correct me if I am wrong. Will look into if I get sometime from work. :)

Comment: This might interest you. Solution looks pretty easy.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548983/binding-data-on-a-model-for-dynamic-nested-forms-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about using nested ng-repeat directives, since a nested loop would be programatically necessary to do this. They do pretty much the same in AngularUI. Check "Sortable" directive in http://angular-ui.github.com/

The alternative would be to write a custom ng-repetable-deeply directive, which would be much more complicated and you'd end up doing a nested loop on that directive anyway.